# Change height of UISearchController view height in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I have a UISearchController added onto my view, but I would like to change the height of it. This is what I have:

```
func initSearch() {
    // Create the search controller and make it perform the results updating.
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .Black

    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [ "Any", "Title", "Content", "Keywords" ]

    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}

@IBAction func searchTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Present the view controller.
    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Below is a screenshot of what it looks like. I would like trim some space from the height though. How can this be done?

[image]